# How to check a specific column on every Repository hit for a specific table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-3.0, abp

Tech: .Net Core, EF Core 3.0, Abp

Got an "Enabled" column on a table and instead of going through every `Repository.GetAll()` hit and add `.Where(w => w.Enabled)` is there a way I can make this a default check?

I have had a search around "Global Filters" but not exactly finding what I think I'm expecting.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, that is exactly what Global Filters are for.
In your DbContext, you would specify what tables have an IsEnabled flag, and it would be automatically applied.

https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-global-filter

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=CustomerDB;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasQueryFilter(c => !c.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

If you happen to have any queries that don't need the global filter applied, you can use IgnoreQueryFilters() on your query.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var customers = context.Customers
        .IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I couldn't seem to find a concrete answer. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question, please accept is as an answer. It helps people who find this post in the future via Google or something :-)